# Python win32crypt.CryptProtectData difference between 2.5 and 3.1?

Tags: python, winapi, python-3.x, remote-desktop, python-2.5

I'm trying to hash a password to dump into a .rdp file. I found a site that (more or less) shows how to do that [here](http://www.remkoweijnen.nl/blog/2007/11/05/encrypt-rdp-password-in-python/) but it doesn't work in 3.1.

In 2.5.4 I get this:

```
>>> import win32crypt
>>> import binascii
>>> pwdHash = win32crypt.CryptProtectData(u"password",u'psw',None,None,None,0)
>>> print str(binascii.hexlify(pwdHash)).upper()
01000000D08C9DDF0115D1118C7A00C04FC297EB010000007E9E... blah, blah blah
```

In 3.1 I get this (everything's unicode in 3.1 so just ditch the u" right?):

```
>>> pwdHash = win32crypt.CryptProtectData("password",'psw',None,None,None,0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#19>", line 1, in <module>
    pwdHash = win32crypt.CryptProtectData("password",'psw',None,None,None,0)
TypeError: expected an object with a buffer interface
```

OK, I've seen that error before and usually that just means I need to convert to bytes first, so:

```
>>> pwdHash = win32crypt.CryptProtectData("password".encode(),'psw',None,None,None,0)
>>> print(str(binascii.hexlify(pwdHash)).upper())
B'01000000D08C9DDF0115D1118C7A00C04FC297EB010000007E9E... blah, blah, blah
>>>
```

Which seems all well and good but that doesn't work when you dump that hexed value into an .rdp file, I can only assume that's because it isn't a hex-crypt of the unicode string 'password' but a hex-crypt of the bytes 'password'. I've attempted a .decode() but that does just what you'd expect and makes the hex-crypt bytes into a string, it doesn't give you the hex-crypt string for the original unicode string.

I've googled like crazy for any info on the win32crypt.CryptProtectData and I can't find any useful information on why it now requires a bytes or buffer object instead of a string.

Can anybody help?
(or does anyone know of an easier way to feed a password into a Remote Desktop session I'm opening programatically through Python? hehe)

Comment: I think the conversion to bytes loses the unicode support, but you can confirm this by dumping the bytes, password should be something like 0x70,0x00,0x61,0x00,0x73,0x00,0x73 and so on. If you get 0x70,061,0x73... then you have ansi instead of unicode... It may be worthwile to check the other articles I wrote about Password Hashing: 

http://www.remkoweijnen.nl/blog/2007/10/18/how-rdp-passwords-are-encrypted/

http://www.remkoweijnen.nl/blog/2007/10/17/launch-rdp-from-commandline/

http://www.remkoweijnen.nl/blog/2008/03/02/how-rdp-passwords-are-encrypted-2/

Comment: The code you give is the code that works. Not what does *not* work. show us the code that doesn't work, and the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use "password".encode('utf-16-le') instead.